# Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id and cannot be print

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This script try to save the data filled up in a form (sheet OD) inside of the spreadsheet then save the data to a sheet (Ordenes Ventas), the script also look for sell already saved and bring to the form to be edited and save again. In Form (OD) i use a data validation from a sheet "Price" where i import the data importrange from another sheet where we have the stock of our products. I do not know if that it is the problem.

i would like to ask for help, because i have not been able to find the error in the script i am trying to use a form inside of google spreadsheet, in the sheet "OV" but I have been not able to put the data with the script in the sheet "Ordenes Ventas". The script sometime works and mostly does not work at all for the same error

> Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id

I create a spreadsheet without importrange and more simple where you can see that script work
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dhYofjrcb4aOV-Z5xNEboBQ4DeBjuJe71z7Y9DwjMQs/edit?usp=sharing

And i create a copy from the file i have the error

> Exception: Service Spreadsheets failed while accessing document with id.

In this I do not know what it is the problem
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AUfVirrraEpCaXYSYOg970sr36PzZnAIk55a_YIvRe8/edit?usp=sharing

This is the code

```
var SerMantSsID="";
var Fila;
var OV;
var OVOVenta;
var OrdenesVentas;
var PreciosStock;
var PreciosOV;
var PreciosStock;
var PreciosStock1;
var PreciosStock2;
var orderid;

function initVars()
{
  /*
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  Logger.log( ss.getName() )

  OV = ss.getSheetByName("OV");
  OrdenesVentas = ss.getSheetByName("Ordenes Ventas");
  */

  OV = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SerMantSsID).getSheetByName("OV");
  OrdenesVentas = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SerMantSsID).getSheetByName("Ordenes Ventas");
  
  //Casilla de la orden en Ordenes Ventas
  orderid = OV.getRange("B6").getValue();
  
  var Fila = OrdenesVentas.getRange("A3:A").createTextFinder(orderid).matchEntireCell(true).findNext();

  OVOVenta = OV.getRange("AF3:DQ3").getValues();
}


function SetValores()
{  
  initVars();

  //Copiado de valores a Ordenes Ventas de nueva orden 
  if (Fila==null){
    OrdenesVentas.getRange(OrdenesVentas.getLastRow()+1,1,1,90).setValues(OVOVenta);

  }else {
    
    OrdenesVentas.getRange(Fila,1,1,90).setValues(OVOVenta);
  }
  borrado_copiado();
}

function BuscarPopular()
{  
  initVars();

  OV.getRange("T6:Z14").copyTo(OV.getRange("B6:H14"),{contentsOnly:true})
  OV.getRange("T18:Y32").copyTo(OV.getRange("B18:G32"),{contentsOnly:true})
 
  //Valor de descuento en valores si es valor dado o compete al calculado por el %
  if (OV.getRange("Z35").getValues() == 
      OV.getRange("Z33").getValues()*OV.getRange("Z34").getValues()){

        OV.getRange("L35").copyTo(OV.getRange("H35"));
        OV.getRange("Z34").copyTo(OV.getRange("H34"));

  } else{
        OV.getRange("H35").setValues(OV.getRange("AO6").getValues());
  }
  
  //Copiar Metodos de pago
  OV.getRange("Y38:Z40").copyTo(OV.getRange("G38:H40"),{contentsOnly:true})
  
  //Copiar formulas a ultimos productos  

  var UltimoProducto = OV.getRange("C18:C32").getValues().filter(String).length;
  OV.getRange(18+UltimoProducto, 12,15-UltimoProducto,6).copyTo(OV.getRange(18+UltimoProducto, 2,15-UltimoProducto,6));

}


//copiar los datos, limpiar los campos de OV a Ordenes de ventas y copiar las formulas de llenado rapido de producto en OV

function borrado_copiado(){
  //Borrado de datos
  
  if( OV == null)
  {
    initVars();
  }

  var rangesToClear = ["B6:H6","B10:H10","B14:H14","B18:F32","F38:F40","H38:H40"];
  for (var i=0; i<rangesToClear.length; i++) {
    OV.getRange(rangesToClear[i]).clearContent();
  }
  //copiado de formula de el consecutivo de la orden de venta Y LA FECHA ACTUAL
  //Orden y fecha 
  OV.getRange("L6:M6").copyTo(OV.getRange("B6:C6"));
  // copiar formula para obtener el nombre del cliente aparte del droplist
  OV.getRange("L10:R10").copyTo(OV.getRange("B10:H10"));
  // copiar formula para obtener el datos bicicleta
  OV.getRange("L14:O14").copyTo(OV.getRange("B14:E14"));
  //copiar formulas de los nombres productos 
  OV.getRange("L18:Q32").copyTo(OV.getRange("B18:G32"));
  // Copiado de precios unidatarios    
  //OV.getRange("O18:O32").copyTo(OV.getRange("G18:G32"));
  // Subtotal descuentos toral
  OV.getRange("R33:R36").copyTo(OV.getRange("H33:H36"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I distilled your function down to two by removing unused variables and eliminating all globals.  You have made some huge mistakes I suggest rewriting the entire this without global variables and keep them as single functions with no sub functions.

```
function SetValores() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ssid");
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("OV");
  const sh2 = ss.getSheetByName("Ordenes Ventas");
  const orderid = sh1.getRange("B6").getValue();
  var orderRanges = sh2.getRange("A3:A" + sh2.getLastRow()).createTextFinder(orderid).matchEntireCell(true).findNext();
  const vs1 = sh1.getRange("AF3:DQ3").getValues();
  if (orderRanges == null) {
    sh2.getRange(sh2.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, 90).setValues(vs1);
  } else {
    sh2.getRange(orderRanges, 1, 1, 90).setValues(vs1);//orderRange is an array of ranges from a createTextfind and it cannot be the first parameter of a getRange
  }
  var rangesToClear = ["B6:H6", "B10:H10", "B14:H14", "B18:F32", "F38:F40", "H38:H40"];
  for (var i = 0; i < rangesToClear.length; i++) {
    sh1.getRange(rangesToClear[i]).clearContent();
  }
  sh1.getRange("L6:M6").copyTo(sh1.getRange("B6:C6"));
  sh1.getRange("L10:R10").copyTo(sh1.getRange("B10:H10"));
  sh1.getRange("L14:O14").copyTo(sh1.getRange("B14:E14"));
  sh1.getRange("L18:Q32").copyTo(sh1.getRange("B18:G32"));
  sh1.getRange("R33:R36").copyTo(sh1.getRange("H33:H36"));
}

function BuscarPopular() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ssid");
  const sh1 = ss.getSheetByName("OV");
  sh1.getRange("T6:Z14").copyTo(sh1.getRange("B6:H14"), { contentsOnly: true })
  sh1.getRange("T18:Y32").copyTo(sh1.getRange("B18:G32"), { contentsOnly: true })
  //you cannot compare 2 dimensional arrays like this. You will have to iterate throught and compare them line by line value by value
  if (sh1.getRange("Z35").getValues() == sh1.getRange("Z33").getValues() * sh1.getRange("Z34").getValues()) {
    sh1.getRange("L35").copyTo(sh1.getRange("H35"));
    sh1.getRange("Z34").copyTo(sh1.getRange("H34"));
  } else {
    sh1.getRange("H35").setValues(sh1.getRange("AO6").getValues());
  }
  sh1.getRange("Y38:Z40").copyTo(sh1.getRange("G38:H40"), { contentsOnly: true })
  var UltimoProducto = sh1.getRange("C18:C32").getValues().filter(String).length;
  sh1.getRange(18 + UltimoProducto, 12, 15 - UltimoProducto, 6).copyTo(sh1.getRange(18 + UltimoProducto, 2, 15 - UltimoProducto, 6))
}
```

Comment: Hello @Cooper, thanks for helps, i really apreciate. I have use your code in the spreadsheet but when the sheet (Precio)  where i use the function vlookup and xlookup to bring the price or name or sku and also  validated the data with a droplist for the products of the invoice (OV). If the data of Price where is save the prices, name and sku of the products is bigger than 2000 rows the code does not work. if the data is small your code or mine with mistakes works. I do not know what else should i do https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dhYofjrcb4aOV-Z5xNEboBQ4DeBjuJe71z7Y9DwjMQs/edit#gid=0

Comment: You are using terms like price and sku and validated data and invoice and that means nothing to me.  I am  here to help you with scripting so how about we talk script and quit talking about your particular application.   Your line `if (sh1.getRange("Z35").getValues() == sh1.getRange("Z33").getValues() * sh1.getRange("Z34").getValues()) ` will never work.  You will have to interest through the two dimensional array and compare them line by line or perhaps even value by value.  See my explain has nothing to do with price or sku's because I don't care about them.

Comment: that line works when the discount is not calculated by percentage in the invoice and filled by value `if (sh1.getRange("Z35").getValues() == sh1.getRange("Z33").getValues() * sh1.getRange("Z34").getValues())`